# Dell power adapter does not get warm?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, efficiency

Usually I notice that power adapters get warm whether they are being used to power a device or not.

The rectangular Dell computer power adapters, however, do not seem to get warm unless they are plugged into a laptop. Is that because they have a switch or something inside of them to turn them off unless there is a load, or is there some other reason?

[image]

Comment: There could be any number of reasons. Age of the adapter, internal components, the reasons you mentioned (switching, load detection etc), or just better design. Only way to know is to open it up and do some reverse engineering.

Comment: @MCG Well, that is not the only way to know. Somebody who engineers this kind of adapter will know right off the bat. Also, I would expect anyone who works in trade, like a buyer who works for Dell might know as well. So, there are a lot of people who probably know the answer to the question without having to take apart an adapter.

Comment: As the (very good) answer from Olin shows, there are a number of reasons. Yes, there are people who know, but those people will likely work for Dell, and be unlikely to share those designs with the rest of the internet!

Comment: @MCG Saying only Dell engineers know is absurd. Anybody who has cut apart such an adapter can immediately find out. Also, I suspect anybody who repairs such things or makes any competing product would know as well. So, there are a large number of people who could know the definitive answer to the question.

Comment: Fair point about people who cut apart and repair them. Depending on the method of course. Point 2 and 3 in Olins answer show many methods that make reverse engineering difficult for someone unless they have previous knowledge on the circuit. And I didn't say Dell engineers only. I said most likely, again, depending on the method it could be Dell specific, meaning any average joe repairman wont know the ins and outs. And, a Dell specific method means people who make competing products would also not know. So no, it is not an absurd claim, it just depends on the method

Comment: Also, if you are confident that "anyone who has cut apart such an adapter" could "immediately find out", then why don't you do just that if you are so curious? Then write up your findings in an answer?

Comment: @MCG Well, I thought somebody might have already done that, which is why I asked the question. Also, since the question has been closed, I can no longer post an answer if I find one.

Comment: Then if you find an answer, edit the question to make it on topic if you wish to re-open it

Answer (score 3):

If they don't get warm when not supplying power, then they have low *quiescent power*.  There are several ways to achieve this:

These supplies could be optimized to use very little power when not supplying any.  That could be well under 1 W, to the point you wouldn't notice the temperature increase in a case that size.

As you say, there could be a special circuit that disables most of the power section if nothing is attempting to draw current.  That still requires some standby DC power so that attempts to draw current from it are detected.

There could be private communication between the laptop and the supply.  The supply doesn't turn on fully until the laptop identifies itself and requests the higher power.  This mechanism can also be used to deter competitors offering the same supply for less money, without the large markup for the brand name.

In the end you'd have to get information from Dell to know for sure.  My guess is #1, since it's really not that hard to do, and simpler than the other means.  With the USB type-C power managing standard, I expect a lot of these proprietary chargers will disappear quite soon.  Many new products already use USB type-C for charging.

Comment: First off, +1 for covering different methods. Second, was wondering why you brought up the USB charging standards, seeing as this is a laptop charger (or looks like it from the picture)? Or is it involved somehow?

Comment: For what it's worth, if this Dell adapter has the 7.4 x 5.0 mm barrel connector with a centre pin then there is communication between the laptop and the supply but it's actually [the other way round](http://www.laptop-junction.com/toast/content/inside-dell-ac-power-adapter-mystery-revealed) - the laptop won't draw power from the supply until it's identified the supply's capabilities.

Comment: @nekomatic that's a great link. That could well point OP in the right direction. While it isn't a definitive answer to the question, it does raise some points of possible methodologies (i.e point 3 in this answer)

Comment: @MCG: New laptops, like the Lenovo I just bought, charge over USB and come with USB type-C chargers.  I expect that will be how just about all such devices will charge in the near future.

Comment: @Olin I didn't know that! Thanks for the clarification on that. It does seem to be the way most things are going these days!